# Securing Session ID Cookie in Weblogic is messing up Session creation

Tags: java, spring, session, cookies

[question]: I am trying to secure the session cookie with simply setting the property of secure cookie to TRUE. However, the application is unable to create the session after this change. 
Does anyone have the same issue ?

This might be something trivial I am missing, but unfortunately I am unable to get this resolved. 
Any help or advise is truly appreciated:

Here is the weblogic.xml setup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90"
    xmlns:j2ee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ....="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90 http://www.oracle.com/technology/weblogic/90/weblogic-web-app">

    <session-descriptor>
            *<cookie-name>JSESSIONIDCA</cookie-name>
            <cookie-path>/../...</cookie-path>
           ..
            <cookie-secure>true</cookie-secure>
    </session-descriptor>
    ...
            <keep-generated>true</keep-generated>
            <page-check-seconds>-1</page-check-seconds>
            <print-nulls>false</print-nulls>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
    ...
    <container-descriptor><servlet-reload-check>-1</servlet-reload-check>    </container-descriptor>
```

I am using: Http Session session = request . get Session();

Application uses Web logic 10.3 and Spring MVC.
Thanks

Comment: Cookie secure should only work with https, so you also need to have a proper ssl configuration (I guess).

Answer (score 2):

Making a Cookie secure, means that the browser will only send it back over https. Hence all http requests will fail after the first request when the cookie is set in the browser. If you are using mixed http/https access to your webserver then you should not make the JSESSIONID cookie secure. If the Auth Cookie Enabled flag is checked which is the default in the weblogic console.

Setting AuthCookieEnabled to true, causes the WebLogic Server instance to send a new secure cookie, _WL_AUTHCOOKIE_JSESSIONID, to the browser when authenticating via an HTTPS connection. Once the secure cookie is set, the session is allowed to access other security-constrained HTTPS resources only if the cookie is sent from the browser.

Thus, WebLogic Server uses two cookies: the JSESSIONID cookie and the _WL_AUTHCOOKIE_JSESSIONID cookie. By default, the JSESSIONID cookie is never secure, but the _WL_AUTHCOOKIE_JSESSIONID cookie is always secure. A secure cookie is only sent when an encrypted communication channel is in use. Assuming a standard HTTPS login (HTTPS is an encrypted HTTP connection), your browser gets both cookies.

for more info please see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13711/thin_client.htm#autoId4